# Inactive remove duplicate labels function, what's up with that?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, labeling

I am using arc 10 and I am having a heck of a time getting duplicate labels to not appear.  The remove duplicate labels in the conflict detection tab is checked but inactive or non selectable.  I don't think I have ever seen it selectable and i can't find another solution to limiting the labelling to one of the grouped points with the same name.  It looks messy and is very frustrating, does anyone have any suggestions.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Removing duplicate labels is not available with point (aka the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s80000000m000000))

> Note:
>
> There are no duplicate label options when labeling point features.

Two workarounds I would try is building a multipoint feature class (using "dissolve") or building a set of polygons (e.g. convex hull or other minimum bounding geometry) that you use as a labeled transparent layer.  Another solution is to convert your label into annotations then manually edit them.